# mysql left join with multiple tables based on user

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I Need to Join two tables car details and favorite cars.I used left join to join both tables.

[image]

[image]

```
|id| name |Model  |registration |Description  |Variant |status|User Detail Id

|1|  Etios    | Mini  | 123123     |AC Available |Petrol  |Active|51

|1|  Etios    | Mini  | 123123     |AC Available |Petrol  |Active|47

|1|  Etios    |  Mini | 123123     |AC Available |Petrol  |Active|52

|6| Indigo    |  Mini | 123        |AC Available |Gas     |Active|NULL
```

This is the output i got but exactly what i need is to display car based on userdetailid.For userdetailid='52' i need to get 3rd and 4th row

I used this query

```
SELECT `u`.`id`,`u`.`CarName`,`u`.`CarModel`,`u`.`RegistrationNumber`,`u`.`Description`,`u`.`Variant`,`u`.`Status`,`uf`.`CardetailsId`,`uf`.`UserDetailsId` 
FROM `cardetails` AS `u`  LEFT JOIN `favoritecars` AS `uf` ON (`u`.`id` = `uf`.`CarDetailsId`) 
where
u.status = 'Active' and u.CarModel = 'Mini'  and (uf.UserDetailsId='52' or uf.UserDetailsId is null)
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `3rd and 4th row` for userid 52? Your 2nd table shows `CarDetailsId 1 and 2 for user 52`, `CarDetailsId 1 is Etios Mini 123123` and `CarDetailsId 2 is Ford Middle K3 TN6456`, which is filtered by your `u.CarModel = 'Mini'` where-clause - You're getting exactly the 1 result you asked in your MySQL statement for.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you question right, your on clause must be 
`ON (u.id = uf.userDetailsId)`

```
SELECT `u`.`id`,`u`.`CarName`,`u`.`CarModel`,`u`.`RegistrationNumber`,`u`.`Description`,`u`.`Variant`,`u`.`Status`,`uf`.`CardetailsId`,`uf`.`UserDetailsId` 
FROM `cardetails` AS `u`  LEFT JOIN `favoritecars` AS `uf` ON (`u`.`id` = `uf`.`userDetailsId`) 
where
u.status = 'Active' and u.CarModel = 'Mini'  and (uf.UserDetailsId='52' or uf.UserDetailsId is
```

Comment: Thank you jens but if Userdetailid is available in favorite cars i need that also because based on that am changing star icon if that car is favorite